# Why margin-bottom disappear with no border

Tags: html, css

Why when i add a border to my container div the bottom margin appear

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="center_div" >
        <div>cc</div>        
        <div>cc</div>  
        <div>cc</div>  
        <div>cc</div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.container {
    border: 1px black solid;
    background-color: pink;   
}


.center_div {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    background-color: beige;
}
```

but when i drop the bottom margin disappear.

```
.container {
    /* border: 1px black solid; */
    background-color: pink;   
}
```

here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DRR4r)

Comment: what you are trying to achieve? your question and given fiddle is not matched !!

Comment: I update the link for the fiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're encountering a problem called margin collapsing. Margin collapsing does not occur between the parent and the child if the parent's border is set. When it happens, the margin of the parent will be the maximum value between the child's margin and the parent's margin **and** the child's margin becomes Zero. When it does not happen, the child's margin is effected normally.

Here is the [Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/nxHet/10/) (no margin-collapsing)  showing that the child's margin appears normally **while** the parent's margin is zero (because we don't set it).
And here is the [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/nxHet/11/) (with margin-collapsing) showing that the child's margin becomes zero **while** the parent's margin is the maximum margin (which is the child's margin `20px`). **Note** the text `Something continues` to see the difference.

To work around you can set the `border-color` to `transparent` like this [Demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/nxHet/12/). You can also set the `overflow` to a value **other than** the `visible`. It's because margin collapse does not happen in such a case. So I think you should set it to `auto`.

Comment: can you explain more about the overflow why it's work in this case ?

Comment: @Youssef I'm not sure why but at least **it's a standard**, it's part of box specification (given by W3C - World Wide Web Consortium), all the browser vendors should implement following that specification, here is the specification about box margin collapsing  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins You can see the second line (in the second Note) in green saying about overflow elements there.

Answer (score 1):

**Now define your** `.container`  `overflow:hidden;`

**as like this**

```
.container{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nxHet/9/)**

Answer (score 1):

i just modified the following css like this.

```
.center_div {
width: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: beige;
}
```

it is working fine now.